# How to redirect with header() with different IP

Tags: php, header

By use this simple code

```
<?php
header("location: http://www.mysite.net/test.php");
?>
```

is possible to redirect from a page to another?

When I check the log on destination server (where is hosted test.php) I see the IP of customer that opens/calls the page. Instead, I need to see the IP of server where original code is hosted.

How to make this without cURL?

Comment: You can't; the server isn't making the request, it's telling the user's browser to do it.

Comment: You'd need to something like `echo file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.net/test.php')`.

Comment: If you could make your own mini log system, you can send where the user come from by url, like `header("location: http://www.mysite.net/test.php?from=place_one");`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it without curl you can pass the data along like so:

```
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.net/test.php?from=' . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);
```

and then on the destination server you could have:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['from'])) {
        echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['from']);
    }
```

The `htmlspecialchars()` function is for sanitization.  The main point here is you pass the servers IP address along in a `$_GET` parameter in the redirect url.